# R - Timeseries, autoplot(), scale_y_continuous(), and the disappearing geom_abline()

Tags: r, plot, scale, timeserieschart, autoplot

I'm attempting to fit a regression line to the some data (mens400 from the fpp2 library).

```
library(fpp2)
library(forecast)

m400 <- tslm(mens400 ~ tm400)
```

I'd like to produce a plot of the data with the regression line included.

```
autoplot(mens400) +
  geom_abline(slope = m400$coefficients[2], intercept = m400$coefficients[1],
              colour = "red")
```

[image]

Unfortunately everything gets squished.  So I adjust the scale using scale_y_continuous:

```
autoplot(mens400) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(40, 60)) +
  geom_abline(slope = m400$coefficients[2], intercept = m400$coefficients[1])
```

[image]

But, my regression line disappears.

The order of the objects doesn't seem to effect the outcome...

How do I get my regression line back?

Comment: Do you get the same result using `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(40, 60))`? Controlling range with `scale_y_continuous` will filter the data (e.g. excluding any data points outside that range), whereas coord_cartesian changes the plotting range after any calculations.

Comment: @Jon Spring coord_cartesian works.  Why not use this as an answer?

Comment: What's tm400 from btw?

Comment: Time Mens 400.  Name derived from 'tm400 <- time(mens400)'.  A time series practice question associated with men’s 400 meters final in each Olympic Games from 1896 to 2016.  From: Forecasting: Principles and Practice (2nd ed), by Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos (I'm not sure of the posting rules on this board, but I can provide the website.